# Why is my freshly formatted external SSD flashing after mounting it on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, ssd, external-hard-drive

I formatted an external SSD connected to my Ubuntu 22.04 box via USB using `mkfs.ext4` and then mounted it.

Problem: The activity LED on the external disk enclosure is flashing since half an hour now and does not stop, although I do not access the filesystem at all. This drives me mad. Will it ever stop flashing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will eventually stop flashing. The kernel process `ext4lazyinit` is running and is slowly initializing the inode tables. It only does this while the filesystem is mounted. Depending on the disk size and number of inodes it may take several hours to complete since it intentionally sleeps between I/O accesses.

This can safely be ignored. The disk can be used immediately.

If you really want to get rid of this delayed initialization, either mount the filesystem with the `init_itable=0` option (which will still initialize the inode tables lazily, but without sleeping between the I/O accesses so it will complete earlier) or you can re-create the filesystem (assuming it is still an empty filesystem! This will erase all your files on this partition!) and disable lazy initialization entirely and wait for the initialization to complete:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdX1 -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0
```